How to get reflection pass when there's no light on the scene
Here's my blend file :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FDAkvG0ZTkOrBIlyMiR9AsOCbOOMysue/view?usp=sharing
There's no light - only use default world lighting.
I combine 2 render layers using compositor to grab the reflection using render pass.
There are 2 render layer :

2BALLS : Render the 2 spheres using render pass. The shadow/reflection is rendered to separated pass (turn on shadow catcher layer -> view layer/light/shadow catcher )
FLOOR : this layer only render the floor.

Here's the compositor :

The shadow catcher pass is multiplied by the plane/floor to get the reflection.
Here is the result :

Everything works fine here. But I just got the case if I want to make the environment to become pitch black . The problem is If I set the world strength to 0 then the reflection is gone. Seems that it won't work if there's no light at all.


Without using render pass, everything is working fine. This is without render pass /shadow catcher :

How to get the reflection pass while there's no light at all ?in this case, the light only come from emission material (yellow sphere).
